# Modules for Python that can be used as a TFTP server

Tags: python, tftp

Are there any modules for Python, that can be used as a TFTP server? I tried [Tftpy](http://tftpy.sourceforge.net/), but when I try to upload something, it says:

> ERROR:tftpy:Write requests not implemented at this time.

In fact, that's the only function that I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try **tftpgui** from http://code.google.com/p/tftpgui/ but it's GPL'ed.

**UPD**: uploading is available starting with [**TFTPy** 0.5.0+](https://github.com/msoulier/tftpy)

**UPD2**: I personally found [PyPXE](https://github.com/psychomario/PyPXE) minimal hackish TFTP implementation sufficient for bootstrapping virtual machines. If your use case the same as mine - use that.